# Displaying a Javascript widget in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

Hey there Stackoverflow!

I'm trying to create an application that uses a WebView to display a JavaScript widget but I seem to have hit a wall in which I cannot get the widget to display at all. I've done a fair amount of research and I think what I'm trying to do is possible.

This is my main activity

```
public class WebViewAppTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //grab the webview
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

  //grab the webview settings
    WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();

    //enable javascript
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //add a js interface to display the widgets
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

    //load a webpage
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/javascript/index.html");


}
```

}

It loads the file index.html which looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<title>WebView test!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>

<div id="panel">
<section class="episode"></section>
</div>

<script src="https://sourceurl1.js" />
<script src="https://sourceurl2.js" />
<script src="https://sourceurl3.js" />
<script src="https://sourceurl4.js" />

<script src="./widget.js" />
<script src="./top-episodes.js" />
<script>
  var TopEpisodes = new Company.TopEpisodes({
  $element: $('#panel section.episodes')
  });
  TopEpisodes.init({
         mode      : 'realtime',
         range     : { from: 1341911040, to: 1341907200 },
         path      : ["4FB159EB613033AA710006DF"],
         isEpisode : true
  });
</script>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

The only thing that displays when I test my application (Nexus S 4G ICS 4.0.4) is the MyHTML header on a blank white screen. Internet access is enabled in the xml.

Is there something else I need to enable for the WebView settings, or does something look really wrong with my HTML file? Do I need to do something with the addJavaScriptInterface method/within a JS interface?

Anyways I am very stuck and open to any suggestions! Thank you for your time!

**EDIT** There haven't been any response on this question for a couple days, let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify this question or any other details that would help! Or if it is even possible. Thank you!

Comment: Can you run JS loading html files locally like "file:///..." ? Usually it is not possible for security restrictions (see Chrome)

Comment: It let me load the html, I got the idea from the sample on WebViews from the Android Developers website. Thanks for your response! See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've decided to go a different direction with my application due to my lack of experience with both HTML and Javascript.

I am instead going to develop the widget natively in Java using this chart library: http://achartengine.org/ and then update the data using an HttpClient rather than creating it within a WebView in Javascript, because I think that this solution will be easier and quicker for an Android application.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is Wrong, `<script src="<location of js>" />`
Your are not pointing the location Properly,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<title>WebView test!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>

<div id="panel">
<section class="episode"></section>
</div>
<!-- Below is the code if the js in the same location of your index.html file. -->
<script src="sourceurl1.js" />
<script src="sourceurl2.js" />
<script src="sourceurl3.js" />
<script src="sourceurl4.js" />

<!-- Below is the code if the js is outside the location of your index.html file. -->  
<script src="../widget.js" />

<!-- Below is the code if the js is outside the location of your index.html file., inside folder js-->  
<script src="../js/top-episodes.js" />
<script>
  var TopEpisodes = new Company.TopEpisodes({
  $element: $('#panel section.episodes')
  });
  TopEpisodes.init({
         mode      : 'realtime',
         range     : { from: 1341911040, to: 1341907200 },
         path      : ["4FB159EB613033AA710006DF"],
         isEpisode : true
  });
</script>
</html>
```

To Help you more, specify the location of the files

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've decided to go a different direction (see answer) but +1 for your time!